# How to fetch multiple images in a single click from directory

Tags: php, image, directory

This is what I have tried, but it doesn't work

```
<?php

  $handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)) . '/pics/');
  while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
      if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
          echo '<img src="pics/' . $file . '" border="0" class="custom-gallery img-responsive" style="height:150px;"/>';
      }
  }
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by a single click? You are looping through files and echoing `<img>`. Where is the click event dependency?

Comment: you're going to have to define what *"but it doesn't work"* means here. Are you not checking for errors at all? what *do* you get back?

Comment: is the `$file` variable returnig proper filename? You probably give wrong path to the `img` tag

Comment: yeah $file is returning the proper filename,and the path is also correct,the only problem is that its my first try to ask a question over here @KrzysztofJaniszewski

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to loop over the directory.

```
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    echo "$entry\n";
}
```

also pls check the file path of the images